# Not getting any error or response from Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell

I try to call a rest API within PowerShell script, but I fail to get any error or response at all.

```
try { 
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $Headers  -TimeoutSec 10  -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop

    "Result:"    
    Write-Host $result
} catch {
    $_.Exception  
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
```

}

the output is just

```
PS C:\temp> .\PutJSON.ps1
VERBOSE: PUT http://111.1.1.11:2345/a/rest/test with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received -1-byte response of content type
Result:


PS C:\temp> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.228
```

I wonder why I am not getting at least any error. Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the verbose output of `Invoke-RestMethod``? Add the `-Verbose` switch to `Invoke-RestMethod`. Maybe there is an non-terminating error. Therefore also add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Invoke-RestMethod` command. More about non terminating errors -> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/.

Comment: Doesn't help also, I've edited my post with the result

Comment: Start debugging by making the call with Postman. If that succeeds, make sure Powershell makes identical a request with, say, Fiddler.

Comment: Fiddler shows result for the ps1 API call: `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` That is the desired result. but why can't I get this result in PS ?